# Принципы правописания слов

Tags: орфография

**На каком принципе основывается правописание следующих слов?**  плечо- морфологический; флажок-фонетический; подытожить-фонетический; подшутить-морфологический; лестница-традиционный; постилать-фонетический; солнце-морфологический; водовоз-морфологический; ходьба-морфологический; поглядеть-морфологический; звоночек-морфологический; колокольчик-морфологический; кожаный-традиционный; прочитанный-морфологический; выдержка-морфологический; зимовка-фонетический; косьба-морфологический; бесшумный-морфологический; горечь-морфологический; звёздный-морфологический; сторожка-морфологический; надписать-морфологический; заря-традиционный; сбить-морфологический; высота- морфологический; допросить-морфологический.

Comment: Это школьное задание?

Answer (score 1):

Школьные упражнения на данную тему вызывают у меня грустные чувства. Думаю, что наша орфографическая наука еще не представила нам полной и сколько-нибудь приемлемой картины, определяющей  четкую терминологию и действие орфографических принципов, но уже готова спрашивать ее с учащихся!  Соответственно, получается не что иное, как  заучивание практически ненужной и непонятной  информации. Трактовка принципов совершенно произвольная, то есть надо составлять перечень орфографических тем и приписывать каждой из них  какой-либо принцип  по желанию составителей этих соответствий.

Особенно огорчает ФОНЕТИЧЕСКИЙ ПРИНЦИП, который почему-то усматривается, например,  в таких словах, как плечО, разЫскивать. Наше письмо является ФОНЕМАТИЧЕСКИМ, то есть  не отражающим фонетическое чередование звуков, и оно противопоставлено письму ФОНЕТИЧЕСКОМУ, которое это чередование отражает. (Это отступление от основного принципа, которое встречается практически только в приставках на З/С). Оба принципа регулируют написания В СЛАБЫХ ПОЗИЦИЯХ, тогда причем тут указанные слова, в которых гласные находятся в сильных (ударных) позициях.

Также удивляет тот факт, что слово просят соотнести С ОДНИМ ПРИНЦИПОМ. Но ведь каждая буква-орфограмма выбирается по конкретному  правилу, которое соответствует  определенному орфографическому принципу. Получается: сколько орфограмм в слове, столько и принципов, хотя при этом возможно их совпадение.

Comment: София, я во многом с Вами согласна, но в школе таких заданий нет, это что-то выше, если бы учащиеся удосужились поискать соответствие правил принципам, они бы легко нашли.С фонетическим Вы не правы, это не только приставки на з/с,  о-ё после шипящих тоже сюда входит, потому что зависит от ударения: оконч. сущ. под ударением О, без ударения Е-плечОм-пейзажЕм,бАржей-баржОй - как произнесёшь. РазЫскивать - тоже фонетический, по морфологическому мы писали бы разИскивать, ведь корень -ИСК-. Сгласна, что сколько орфограмм, столько и принципов.Каждая орфограмма объясняется своим принципом.

Comment: Термин "фонетический" имеет принципиальное и вполне конкретное значение - не стоило бы его использовать в других (частных) случаях, когда выбор буквы просто связан с ударением как фонетическим средством. И вот выбор Ы/И - почему он фонетический? Чередование Ы/И после мягких и твёрдых согласных – обычное явление для суффиксов и окончаний,  например: разбрасывать – заготавливать, голыш – мякиш  – чередование Ы/И в суффиксах ЫВА/ИВА, ЫШ/ИШ; столы – земли – чередование Ы/И в окончании. Также чередование Ы/И происходит в  корне: искать – обыскать (это норма). А вот  "контригра" - это исключение.

Answer (score 0):

плечо- фонетический; зимовка-морфологический; бесшумный-фонетический;

Comment: Вы уверенны, что «плечо» это только фонетический принцип? Не было бы ли «пличо» более фонетически?

Comment: Я имела в виду о-ё после шипящих, отвечала я Софии, а у неё выделено О

Comment: Под влиянием ответа Софии опустила орфограмму в корне, это точно, там Е-по морфологич. принципу, О-по фонетическому